# Django south cannot import required field

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I upgraded to django to 1.6.x which no longer has `localflavor`. `localflavor` was moved from `django.contrib` to its own module, which I now use in my app. When I do a schemamigration, south tries to preform this change on the database. (Note: the two modules are very closely related if not entirely similar and are cross compatible.)

The problem is that south still tries to import `django.contrib.localflavor`, which does not exist.

What is the correct way to fix this?

This is the error I get (running through fabric):

```
ValueError: Cannot import the required field 'django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.USStateField'

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py migrate --settings=settings.local'
```

Comment: did you update south?

Comment: Have you followed the steps?:
http://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-to-migrate

Comment: Also check:
https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/issues/51

Comment: Changing the namespace in no way affects the south migrations. When migrations are created, south includes `django.contrib.localhost.~~~' in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still having this issue? I just ran into this and figured out the solution.

First open up your latest `myapp/migration/0001_blah_blah_blah.py` migration for for your app.

Then find the go to the models dict or just ctrl+f `django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.USStateField` and replace it with `localflavor.us.models.USStateField`.

After that you should be able to run `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto` successfully and then apply the migration.

Hope this helps and it's not too late!

Cheers.